# Looking for a curve with a special, free $\mathbb{Z}/2$-action

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I am looking for a smooth curve $C$ of genus $g=2k+1 \geq 5$ over the complex numbers, endowed with a *free* $\mathbb{Z}/2$-action such that the following condition is satisfied: denoting by $$H^0(C, \, \omega_C) = V^+ \oplus V^{-},$$ the decomposition of $H^0(C, \, \omega_C)$ into invariant and anti-invariant subspaces, there are bases
$\{ \omega_1, \ldots, \omega_{k+1} \}$ of $V^+$
and $\{\omega_{k+2}, \ldots, \omega_g \}$ of $V^{-}$ such that the divisors $\mathrm{div}({\omega_i})$, $\mathrm{div}({\omega_j})$ have disjoint supports for all $1 \leq i < j \leq g$.

> **Question.** Does such a curve exist?

**What I have tried.** Let me explain one example that does *not* work. I considered a hyperelliptic curve $C$ of affine equation $$y^2=(x^2-a_1^2)\ldots (x^2-a_{2g+2}^2),$$ where the scalars $a_i$ are general. Since $g$ is assumed to be odd, such a curve admits a free $\mathbb{Z}/2$-action given by $(x, \, y) \mapsto (-x, \, -y)$. A basis for $H^0(C, \, \omega_C)$ is given by $$\left \{ \omega_i \; \; | \; \; 0 \leq i \leq g-1 \right \},$$ where $\omega_i=x^i \frac{dx}{y}$. Therefore we have $$V^+=\{\omega_i \, | \, i\textrm{ even} \}, \quad V^-=\{\omega_i \, | \, i\textrm{ odd} \}.$$ This shows that all the $1$-forms in $V^-$ vanish at the points of the curve with $x=0$, hence the condition above cannot be satisfied when $g \geq 5$ (that means $\dim V^- \geq 2$).

Comment: Could we please call that group Z/2 or Z/2Z or $\{ \pm 1\}$ instead of Z_2 ?

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies: I changed the notation (which is however very common in Algebra textbooks)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your examples are the *only* curves with fixed-point-free involution that don't have such a basis.

Let $C_0$ be a curve of genus $k+1$ and let $L$ be a nontrivial line bundle on $C_0$ with $L^2\cong  \mathcal O_{C_0}$. Then $\mathcal O_{C_0}+L$ has a natural algebra structure defined using that isomorphism. The relative Spec is a double cover $C$ of genus $2k+1$. Since it's a double cover, it has a natural involution. All curves with involution arise this way.

This involution acts on $H^0(C, \omega_C)$. The invariant subspace consists of 1-forms that are equal on each of the two fibers of $C \to C_0$, hence are pullbacks from $C_0$, and thus is isomorphic to  $ H^0(C_0 , \omega_{C_0})$, while the anti-invariant subspace consits of 1-forms with opposite values on the two fibers, hence locally pullbacks of 1-forms from $C_0$ multiplied by section of $L$, and thus is isomorphic to $H^0(C_0, \omega_{C_0}\otimes L)$.

For your criterion, it suffices that $\omega_{C_0}$ and $\omega_{C_0}\otimes L$ are both base-point free. Indeed, for a base-point free line bundle, a generic section avoids any given finite set of points, so it is easy to choose a basis where each section in the basis successively avoids the vanishing locus of the previous ones.

By Serre duality, $\omega_{C_0}$ is always base-point-free and $\omega_{C_0} \otimes L$ is base-point free if and only if the divisor class of $L$ can be expressed as the difference of two points of $C_0$.

If $P-Q$ is a two-torsion divisor, then $(2P, 2Q)$ are two divisors of degree $2$ equivalent to each other, thus defining a $g^1_2$, so $C_0$ is hyperelliptic. Even in the hyperelliptic case, this can only happen if $P$ and $Q$ are Weierestrass, so there are $\binom{ 2k+4}{2}$ two-torsion line bundles where such a basis does not exist on the cover, out of $2^{2k+2}-1$ nontrivial two-torsion line bundles total, so there are plenty of line bundles that do work for any $k \geq 2$. For the ones that don't, the cover can be obtained from the double cover of $\mathbb P^1$ branched at the $x$ coordinates of $P$ and $Q$, meaning that, after a change of variables, it's given by your construction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will check the details.

Comment: It seems to me that your argument uses that the involution is base-point free only when you say that $L^2= \mathcal{O}_C$. In the same vein, we could take a divisor $B$ on $C_0$ such that $L^2=\mathcal{O}_{C_0}(B)$, obtaining a double cover $C \to C_0$ branched at $B$. Then, if both $\omega_{C_0}$ and $\omega_{C_0} \otimes L$ are base-point free, we get a smooth curve $C$ with a non-free $\mathbb{Z}/2$-action and satisfying my condition. In fact, in this case, things are easier, since the degree of $\omega_{C_0} \otimes L$ is greater than the degree of $\omega_{C_0}$. Is it correct?

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi Not quite. In this case $H^0(C_0,\omega_{C_0})$ is base-point-free but viewed as a linear system inside $H^0(C,\omega_C)$ has a base point, since when you pull back any 1-form it will vanish at the base points. In the case without branched points, this can't happen.

Comment: So, it seems to me that you are saying that in the branched case the condition cannot be satisfied, unless $g(C_0) \leq 1$ (namely, unless $\dim V^+ \leq 1$). In fact, the linear system corresponding to $V^+$ has always base points at the fixed locus of the involution $f \colon C \to C_0$, since $$\f^*\omega_p(v)=\omega_{f(p)}(df_p(v))$$ and $df_p$ is zero at the ramification points.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi Yes, exactly. Hyperelliptic curves clearly have $V^-$ base-point free, and branched hyperelliptic curves with two or more branch points do, but branched hyperelliptic curves with two branch points don't, since then $\omega_C \otimes L = L$ has degree $1$ and thus always (on an elliptic curve) has a base point.

Comment: I think you have a typo above. I think the penultimate paragraph should read "$\omega \otimes L$ is base point free if and only if $L$ <b>cannot</b> be expressed as $P-Q$".

Comment: @WillSawin: when you wrote "and branched hyperelliptic curves with two or more branch points do but branched hyperelliptic curves with two branch points don't", maybe you meant "bielliptic" instead of "hyperelliptic" and "four or more branch points" instead of "two or more branch points"?

Comment: The conclusion then would be that all $2^{2g}-1$ $2$-torsion classes work for $C_0$ non-hyperelliptic, and $2^{2g}-\binom{2g+2}{2}$ of them work when $C_0$ is hyperelliptic.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Yes, this is perhaps a better way to phrase it, except I think you need another $-1$ in the second formula.

Comment: Yes, you are right, should be $2^{2g} - \binom{2g+2}{2} - 1$. (Note that this is $0$ for $g=2$, so the first examples occur for $g=3$.)

Comment: The following is an explicit formula for what happens in the hyperelliptic case. Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be polynomials of degrees $2a+2 \geq 4$ and $2b+2 \geq 4$, with all roots of $f(x) g(x)$ distinct. Let $C$ be $k[x,y,z]/(y^2 -f(x),\ z^2 - g(x))$, and let the involution switch the signs of both $y$ and $z$. Then $V^+$ is forms pulled back from the hyperelliptic curve $w^2 = f(x) g(x)$, meaning $x^i dx / yz$ for $0 \leq i <  a+b+1$, and $V^-$ is spanned by the forms pulled back from $y^2 = f(x)$ and from $z^2 = g(x)$, meaning $x^j dx/y$ for $0 \leq j < a$ and $x^k dx/z$ for $0 \leq k < b$.